# Why print statement does not print a new line

Tags: python

I have read the Python docs about the `print` statement. With the following situation (2) not understood.

> A space is written before each object is (converted and) written,
>   unless the output system believes it is positioned at the beginning of
>   a line. This is the case
>
> 1. when no characters have yet been written to standard output,
> 2. when the last character written to standard output is a whitespace character except `' '`, or
> 3. when the last write operation on standard output was not a `print` statement.

I have test this behavior with the following code. However, it does not print `1` and `2` on different lines since `'\t'` is a whitespace and is obviously not a `' '`.

```
print 1, '\t',
print 2
```

Comment: You have included a trailing comma, which *explicitly* suppresses the newline.

Comment: And you are a decade behind, upgrade to Python 3 now!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt only six years, so far!

Comment: @jonrsharpe, so in order to print a string in a new line, i only have to write a  `print` clause without a trailing comma. Does it have another way to do this.

Comment: @andy 1. Try it and see! 2. Per the Zen of Python (`import this`) *"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."*. Although if you `from __future__ import print_function` you can use 3.x's `print` implementation, and explicitly specify the `end` for each call.